# Creating a RegEx which skips commas within curly brackets and within square brackets

Tags: php, regex

I have the following RegEx:

```
,|\{[^]]+\}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
```

Which ignores commas within curly brackets. So the following comma is ignored:

> {hi,there}

However, I also need it to ignore both commas in curly brackets and commas nested within square brackets which lie within curly brackets. So the comma in the following should be ignored:

> {"stars":[6,5]}

Can anyone suggest a RegEx. Thanks

Comment: Please indicate which language or library you are using. Not all regexes are the same.

Comment: @JDB I didn't realise that. I genuinely don't know. I'm using the RegEx as an argument in PHP's preg_split function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might do is match the opening `{`, then match either not any of the chars listed in this character class `[^{}\r\n\]\[]` or when you do encounter an opening `[` match until the closing one.

If have added newlines to the character class to prevent crossing lines in the demo and escaped all the `[]` for clarity.

```
,|{(?:[^{}\r\n\]\[]|\[[^\r\n\]]*\])*}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
```

- `,` Match comma
- `|` Or
- `{` match opening {
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[^{}\r\n\]\[]` Match any character that is not in the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
  - `|` Or
  - `\[[^\r\n\]]*\]` Match from `[` till closing `]`
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `}` Match closing }
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WqTbXX/1)

Another option could be to match all between `{` to  `}`

```
,|\{[^{}\r\n]*\}(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/g5rhjr/1)